# How to select records which have particular value if not then use different value in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to select some records from a table where phone_type ='PR' if record does not have phone_type ='PR' then use 'CL'

Table:

```
ID NAME    Phone_Type Phone_Number
1  Austin  PR         789-100-1000
1  Austin  CL         762-100-1009
1  Austin  PA         789-100-1000
2  Andrew  PR         565-100-1000
2  Andrew  CL         312-199-6754
2  Andrew  FA         602-100-1000
3  Kathy   CL         100-100-1000
3  Kathy   PA         105-109-1002
```

The result should be like this:

```
ID NAME    Phone_Type Phone_Number
1  Austin  PR         789-100-1000
2  Andrew  PR         565-100-1000
3  Kathy   CL         100-100-1000
```

One of the SQL code I tried:

```
select id, name,phone_number_combined,case when phone_type = 'CL' then phone_number_combined end
from telephone where phone_type = 'PR'
```

I am not sure how to achieve this in SQL as I have tried CASE statements, exists and even tried joining the table with itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use `GROUP BY` by and `COALESCE`:

```
WITH telephone (id, name, phone_type, phone_number) AS 
  ( SELECT * FROM  (VALUES  
    ( 1,  'Austin', 'PR', '789-100-1000'),
    ( 1,  'Austin', 'CL', '762-100-1009'),
    ( 2,  'Andrew', 'PR', '565-100-1000'),
    ( 2,  'Andrew', 'CL', '312-199-6754'),
    ( 3,  'Kathy' , 'CL', '100-100-1000')  )) 
    
   select 
      id as ID, 
      name as NAME,
      COALESCE( max(case when phone_type = 'PR' then 'PR' end),
                max(case when phone_type = 'CL' then 'CL' end) ) as PHONE_TYPE, 
      COALESCE( max(case when phone_type = 'PR' then phone_number end),
                max(case when phone_type = 'CL' then phone_number end) ) as PHONE_NUMBER
    from telephone 
    group by id, name 
    order by id, name

 ----    
 Results
 ID   NAME      PHONE_TYPE  PHONE_NUMBER
 1    Austin    PR          789-100-1000
 2    Andrew    PR          565-100-1000
 3    Kathy     CL          100-100-1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [row_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function.

```
-- Oracle
with s (id, name, phone_type, phone_number) as ( 
select 1,  'Austin', 'PR', '789-100-1000' from dual union all
select 1,  'Austin', 'CL', '762-100-1009' from dual union all
select 2,  'Andrew', 'PR', '565-100-1000' from dual union all
select 2,  'Andrew', 'CL', '312-199-6754' from dual union all
select 3,  'Kathy' , 'CL', '100-100-1000' from dual)
select  id, name, phone_type, phone_number
from
   (select
    id, name, phone_type, phone_number,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by phone_type desc) rn
    from s
    )
where rn = 1;

        ID NAME   PHONE_TYPE PHONE_NUMBER
---------- ------ ---------- ------------
         1 Austin PR         789-100-1000
         2 Andrew PR         565-100-1000
         3 Kathy  CL         100-100-1000

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: What if the table has more than 1000 records and Phone_Type - FA and PA also included. Would the above query still work? @nbk

Comment: What would you want to get as result if there's FA as well? If you post incomplete question, don't expect to get a *perfect* answer. Make up your mind.

Comment: Why you didn't say about FA and PA at first? You need modify order by clause of my query using decode or case expression.

Comment: @Littlefoot I did not want to post the whole question as it contains so many multiple values with other indicators. I am not expecting  the perfect answer to my whole problem. I just needed to know what could I use for simple problem from there I can modify.

Comment: @akk0rd87 Thank you much for your quick response. I totally forgot about the row number function.